# Difference between unlocked iPhone 6 from T-Mobile vs. regular unlocked iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, unlock

I'm trying to understand what is the difference between buying an unlocked iPhone 6 with T-Mobile SIM versus just a regular unlocked iPhone 6? They seem to be the same price:
http://store.apple.com/us/buy-iphone/iphone6/4.7-inch-display-64gb-silver

Apple's [info page](http://store.apple.com/us/browse/overlay/iphone/about_unlocked) states this:

> Purchasing an unlocked iPhone means you will not qualify for the lower
>   iPhone price associated with a contract or a carrier installment plan.
>   The unlocked iPhone 6 model is A1586. The unlocked iPhone 6 Plus model
>   is A1524. The T-Mobile iPhone 6 model is A1549. The T-Mobile iPhone 6
>   Plus model is A1522. For details on LTE network support, please see
>   www.apple.com/iphone/LTE.

Can someone translate it?

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely at http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/, the SIM-Free unlocked models (A1586, A1524) supports ALL of the LTE bands of the T-Mobile unlocked phones (A1549,A1522), PLUS some additional networks.

Here is the exact verbiage on the page (easy to overlook): "Models A1586 and A1524 **also support** LTE networks listed for models A1549 and A1522." which basically means "same as the T-Mobile phone ... and then some..."

I picked up a 6 and 6plus sim-free earlier this year to be used on our mobile share value AT&T plan in the US; the Apple Store employee essentially pushed me out the door with the SIM-free model. Said it had additional bands, potentially better resale value, etc...

Hope this helps clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different standards for cellular communication in America, so there's an iPhone to account for each one of those.

iPhone 6 (GSM/North America)

A1549

iPhone 6 (CDMA/Verizon)

A1549

iPhone 6 (Global/Sprint)

A1586

iPhone 6 (China Mobile)

A1589

Source and more details: [everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/iphone-faq/differences-between-iphone-6-models.html)